# XSLT Cannot Find <tr> Attributes Inside Table

Tags: html, xml, xslt, alignment, tr

**Problem**

I am currently working on a transformation function to take a given HTML file and convert it into a custom XML using XSLT 2.0. I have had success transforming everything except for the align attribute for  tags inside of a table.

The HTML document I am currently having issues with looks as follows:

```
<table frame="none" style="margin-left:0">
   <tbody>
      <tr align="left">
         <th style="text-align:left; vertical-align:top; border-right:1 solid black; border-bottom:1 solid black">Yeah</th>
         <th style="text-align:left; vertical-align:top; border-right:1 solid black; border-bottom:1 solid black">4321</th>
      </tr>
      <tr align="left">
         <th style="text-align:left; vertical-align:top; border-right:1 solid black; border-bottom:1 solid black">Blah</th>
         <th style="text-align:left; vertical-align:top; border-right:1 solid black; border-bottom:1 solid black">1234<sup>3</sup></th>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

First I have targeted the table by using:

```
<xsl:template match="table">
```

Then I go through the table and grab various tag and attributes needed for the transformation using choose and when cases. But when I try and get the align attribute using the following when case it always fails:

```
<xsl:when test="tbody/tr[1]/@align">
    <xsl:attribute name="align"><xsl:value-of select="tbody/tr[1]/@align"/></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:when>
```

**Troubleshooting**

After doing some debugging I found out that if I use the following case it finds the  tag just fine:

```
<xsl:when test="tbody/tr[1]">
    <xsl:attribute name="align"><xsl:value-of select="'Found TR'"/></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:when>
```

I have also tested the XPath in google chrome and found that the tbody/tr[1]/@align path is valid and works fine.

One weird thing I found out is that for some reason under the style tab in google chrome dev tool the align attribute is listed as:

```
tr[Attributes Style] {
    text-align: -webkit-left;
}
```

After finding this out I tried to use the following when case and still it fails:

```
<xsl:when test="tbody/tr[1]/@text-align">
        <xsl:attribute name="align"><xsl:value-of select="tbody/tr[1]/@text-align"/></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:when>
```

**TLDR:** I can target a tr tag inside of a table but I cannot grab the align attribute using XSLT 2.0.

I am obviously not an expert in XSLT so any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say "..It always fails". Are you getting an error, for example. It would probably help if you showed a complete XSLT that demonstrated your actual issue, rather than a small snippet, as maybe something else is coming into play..... Note that, in the example you have given, you could just ditch the `xsl:choose` / `xsl:when` and do `<xsl:copy-of select="tbody/tr[1]/@align" />` instead. Thanks

Comment: No I am not getting any error messages and the rest of the transformation is happening correctly. It's just the tr align attribute is not coming through on the final xml. I'll have to try the copy-of way cause I didn't know of that. Thanks

Comment: So i tried the copy-of but it still cannot find the @align attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In your second example, that `text-align` is not an attribute. It is `style` that is an attribute, and `text-align` is just part of the attribute value. It looks like `<tr align="left">` is being converted to `<tr style="text-align: left" >` before your XSLT gets hold of it.

Extracting the "value" of text-align from the style attribute is tricky, but possible. As you are using XSLT 2.0, you could do something like this...

```
  <xsl:variable name="tokens" select="tokenize(tbody/tr[1]/@style, ';')" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains(tbody/tr[1]/@style, 'text-align')">
      <xsl:attribute name="align" select="substring-after($tokens[substring-before(., ':') = 'text-align'], ':')" />
    </xsl:when> 
  </xsl:choose>
```

So, it splits up the attribute value by the `;` separator, and finds the part that starts with "text-align"

Comment: So I just tried this and it is still not finding the align. While testing my XPaths in the chrome console i found that $x("contains(//tbody/tr[1]/@align, 'left')") returns true while $x("contains(//tbody/tr[1]/@style, 'text-align')") returns false. when i use $x("contains(//tbody/tr[1]/@align, 'left')")  in my when statement it still fails the test